# Visa to get out of the airport during a 12-hour layover in Amsterdam

Tags: visas, transit, amsterdam, ams, egyptian-citizens

I'm a permanent resident of Canada, and I have my Egyptian passport. I'm going to Cairo by KLM, I will stay for more than 12 hours in the airport, and I would like to go out for a quick trip in downtown Amsterdam. I tried to book an appointment here in Canada for a visa, but the nearest one is after my flight! Is there any way I can get out and come back, such as getting a visa for a short stay from the airport – is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know, as an Egyptian citizen, you can transit without visa if you stay in the international arrival lounge. However, it will not be possible to leave the airport without Schengen visa and you will not be able to apply for such a visa at the airport.